# "Hot Network Questions" should be available

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app, hot-questions

The most common way I browse SE is using the HNQ list, but I can't get to this via the app.
Can we have a way to filter the feed to just be populated from HNQ?

Comment: That's noise that I think I can do without on the limited space of an iPhone screen.